# What is Fiddler and how do I turn it off?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

Pretty much straight forward question. I've tried to look this up but the results that I've found have been very vague. I'm busy with a Windows Phone app and have been running into some problems. I've read with Fiddler on you might run into some problems, but that's beside the point right now...

What is fiddler and how do I know if it's 'on'? Plus how to I turn it off if it is?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler is a data monitoring tool that allows you to see incoming and outgoing HTTP(s) traffic from your computer. http://fiddler2.com/

It is a desktop app, so if you haven't got it installed on your PC - then you don't need to turn it off

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is a tool that helps you monitor your HTTP(S) traffic. It's great for debugging any network issues you're having as it lets you trace where your data is going and coming in from. If you haven't installed it, then you won't have it on your machine by default.

Comment: Minor quibble, `HTTP(S) traffic` rather than `internet traffic`.

Comment: Minor but important distinction. Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

**Monitor HTTP/HTTPs traffic from any browser**

Fiddler is a free web debugging proxy which logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Use it to debug traffic from virtually any application that supports a proxy like IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, and more.

**Inspect and debug traffic from any client**

Debug traffic from PC, Mac, or Linux systems and mobile devices. Ensure the proper cookies, headers, and cache directives are transferred between the client and server. Supports any framework, including .NET, Java, Ruby, etc.

**Tamper client requests and server responses**

Easily manipulate and edit web sessions. All you need to do is set a breakpoint to pause the processing of the session and permit alteration of the request/response. You can also compose your own HTTP requests to run through Fiddler

**Test the performance of your web sites and apps**

Fiddler lets you see the “total page weight,” HTTP caching, and compression at a glance. Isolate performance bottlenecks with rules like “Flag any uncompressed responses larger than 25kb.”

**Decrypt HTTPS web sessions**

Use Fiddler for security testing your web applications -- decrypt HTTPS traffic, and display and modify requests using a man-in-the-middle decryption technique. Configure Fiddler to decrypt all traffic, or only specific sessions.

**Extend Fiddler as much as you want**

Benefit from a rich extensibility model which ranges from simple FiddlerScript to powerful Extensions which can be developed using any .NET language. See full list of ready-made add-ons.